# WordPress - FlickrRSS, Flickr Gallery - BOTH not working

Tags: php, ajax, debugging, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been stumped by this simplest problem for hours now, turning to my friends at StackOverflow :)

Basically, I'm developing a custom WordPress theme.  I'm using the same code that I have used many times before from EightFaces "FlickrRSS" plugin.  Code looks like this:

```
<?php 
  get_flickrRSS(
       array(
         'set' => '72157625440574627', 
         'num_items' => 20, 
         'type' => 'set'
       )
  ); 
?>
```

The problem (which is very difficult to troubleshoot) is that I get absolutely ZERO return from the above code.  So far I have tried different users and different Photo Sets, with no luck.

Frustrated by being unable to debug, I tried a different plugin the "Flickr Gallery" plugin which has high ratings also.  Using the shortcodes for this gallery I again get ABSOLUTELY NOTHING.

I thought that perhaps my server somehow got reset to PHP 4, but that's not it, it's set for PHP 5.

Also, occurred to me that it might be WordPress 3.03.  This site is the only one of those I've developed using WordPress 3.03.

I'm totally stumped.  Anyone out there seen this problem or even have suggestions for debugging?  I'll try anything (as long as I haven't tried it already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is setup properly, but I think you have the wrong value for "set".

I went through your user profile, found your site, and from there I found your Flickr account. When I navigate to http://www.flickr.com/photos/brianfeister/sets/72157625440574627/ I get a 404.

Either you have the wrong set number, or you have it set to private or something.

Edit:

It took a while, but I figured out the problem.

According to the README file that comes with the plugin, the 'id' field is only needed when 'type' is set to 'user' or 'group', but it turns out that it's needed with 'set' as well.

If I run this:

```
  get_flickrRSS(
    array(
      'set' => '72157624166201871', 
      'num_items' => 5, 
      'type' => 'set' 
    )
  )
```

I get nothing, but if I add the 'id' field (i.e. the 'id' for the user owning the set, not your 'id'):

```
  get_flickrRSS(
    array(
      'set' => '72157624166201871', 
      'num_items' => 5, 
      'type' => 'set', 
      'id' => '51236489@N06'
    )
  )
```

It works.

Comment: Interesting... you are half-correct.  Use this as an example... this is the gallery I'm trying to get right now: http://www.flickr.com/photos/cristinabellydancer/sets/72157624166201871/  I just added that in the array and still get nothing.

Comment: Wow, that seems like it should totally solve it, but alas, for me I still get nothing.  The code you posted above I copied directly into my php theme file between "portraits" and the YouTube embed frame at this URL: http://easterndancer.com.s66112.gridserver.com/photos/

Comment: @Brian: I just noticed those code samples were missing a closing paren. Could that be it? If not, are you sure you're editing the right file? Could it be that simple?

Comment: Here's my code:      <?php get_flickrRSS(
                       array(
                       'set' => '72157624166201871', 
                       'num_items' => 5, 
                       'type' => 'set', 
                        'id' => '51236489@N06'
                       )); ?>

Comment: And I have made other changes that display (like the video embed was a recent add and it showed up fine)

Comment: Now you know how I feel after working on this for like 4 or 5 hours or something.  Banging my head against a brick wall :/

Comment: Totally random issue.  It ended up working after I deleted and re-installed the plugin :/